# How to set base class members before derived class constructor is called?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, components, protected

There is a base class for components of my application which provides some members and the functions `Init()` and `Update()` which must be overwritten.

```
class Component
{
public:
    void Set(type* Member1, type* Member2, type* Member3)
    {
        this->Member1 = Member1;
        this->Member2 = Member2;
        this->Member3 = Member3;
    }
    virtual void Init() = 0;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
    virtual ~Component() {}
protected:
    type* Member1;
    type* Member2;
    type* Member3;
};
```

For handeling the components, there is a manager. It first sets the members of a component and then calls `Init()` on it. Later on it can be used to update all assigned components but that isn't related to this question.

```
class Manager
{
public:
    void Add(string Name, Component* Component)
    {
        list[Name] = Component;
    }
    void Init(type* Member1, type* Member2, type* Member3)
    {
        for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
        {
            i->second->Set(Member1, Member2, Member3);
            i->second->Init();
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
            i->second->Update();
    }
private:
    unordered_map<string, Component*> list;
};
```

I am not really happy with my implementation since I would like components to use their constructor for initialization instead overwriting the `Init()` function. But at construction time the base class member aren't available yet.

I know that I could pass the members through the derived class constructor, but I do not want specific components to care about their base class' members. That would look like the following but anyway I do not want that.

```
class Component
{
public:
    Component(type* Member1, type* Member2, type* Member3)
    {
        this->Member1 = Member1;
        this->Member2 = Member2;
        this->Member3 = Member3;
    }
    virtual void Update() = 0;
    virtual ~Component();
protected:
    type* Member1;
    type* Member2;
    type* Member3;
};

class Specific : public Component
{
public:
    Specific(type* Member1, type* Member2, type* Member3) : Component(Member1, Member2, Member3)
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
};
```

So how can I insure that the base class members are initialized before calling the constructor of the derived class?

Comment: When you Member initializer list the Base class constructor will be called before you enter the body of the derived class constructor.

Comment: "I do not want specific components to care about their base class' members" Then why on earth did you declare them as `protected`?

Comment: @Lundin. Specific components should use them but shouldn't care about their initialization.

Comment: @AlokSave. I know that's why I told you that I would not prefer that solution since I don't want a specific component to care about initialization of these base class members.

Comment: @KerrekSB. I claim to know them. Could you please explain how you would change my code using constructor initializer lists correctly?

Comment: Yeah. Hmm... this code is a bit puzzling. I would probably want to redesign to not have any useless "default" states that need to be rewritten with an init-function, I suppose.

Comment: @KerrekSB. Since I need help with that, I asked this question.

Comment: I should just note that protected attributes are a design smell by themselves, and it sounds like you may be using public inheritance as a hybrid interface/containment rather than just to apply an interface. With more information on your underlying problem (and why the members need to be set later for example) we could probably provide an alternate approach that would address your conerns.

Comment: @MarkB I agree with that. sharethis, in a correct public inheritance hierarchy, a derived class object is also a base class object: it makes no sense saying that your derived objects should not care about their base class members. It looks like you should rethink your design.

Comment: @MarkB. I want to provide an abstraction layer for developing separate components for my graphics application. They should not care about the protected members because I want to hide implementation details of the system. If someone wants to extend my application, he just should derive from the component base class and start programming. That is the idea behind that. Sadly I think this is a bit against standard C++ style so there might be no way around using a fake constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have a choice. Either the derived class knows about the initialisation needs of the base class (because the base class needs that information in its constructor/initialisation function), or you have to move the derive-class' initialisation out of its constructor (to be called by the client after it initialised the base class).

If the list of members that need to be set on the base class is long, you could package them all in a structure and pass that, via the derived class, to the base class.

Comment: I like the compromise you described in the last paragraph. Maybe I will go that way.

Answer (score 0):

The base-class constructor is called before the derived class constructor, so set the values in your base-class constructor.

Comment: I do not want to pass the member values through the derived class constructor to manually call the base class constructor in the initializer list.

Comment: So, then I see no reasonable solution. Basically, what you want to do doesn't work in the architecture of the class structure you are using. Someone else may have some clever way to do it, but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're tryign to accomplish here but I can make a few observations. It looks like you may be trying to implement two-phase construction.

First, if you want to use the base class constructor you will *have* to pass through the values from the derived constructor. There's no other mechanism in the language to do it, so if that's not an option (or at least not one you want to entertain) then you'll have to use an additional external interface.

To answer your final question, the members of the base are *always* initialized before the derived constructor is called. I'll assume you want to make sure they're set before using `Update` for example.

What about making `Init` protected, and renaming `Set` to something like `SetAndInit` and forcing it to always do the set before it calls the `Init` function. That prevents you from calling `Init` before the base members are set and still gives you a relatively similar interface.

Comment: You are right, I meant *set* instead of *initialized*. About the your idea in the last paragraph: This wouldn't solve my problem and not calling `Init()` before `Set()` is ensured already since both calls are right after each other in the code.